# Unable to plot 3D medical images in Python using Numpy and Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I would like to plot 3D medical images using Python, Numpy and Matplotlib. I have been to trying to use the following snippet to display them but the image itself does not render.

```
import os
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def make_ax(grid=False):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")
    ax.set_zlabel("z")
    ax.grid(grid)
    return ax

x=os.listdir('Path to .dcm images')
print(x)
vol = imageio.volread('Path to .dcm images') 
print(vol.shape)

ax = make_ax(True)
ax.voxels(vol, edgecolors='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the image that i am getting as output.]

---

[Link for data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JK3m6unOgKF_pYUYH5M4Xbrw7-K-eOzV)

Comment: Have you considered to look at a subset of your data? Providing a sample data set would help getting the answer you need.

Comment: Posted link for data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`voxel` expects boolean values - or something that can be treated as a boolean, according to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/voxels.html).  You are passing integer data, anything non-zero is treated as true.  Most of your data is non-zero, so you get the big grey cube that you've shown.  There's nothing wrong with the way it's being rendered - you've just chosen the wrong way to visualize the data you have.